# TestNG: repeat a method

Tags: testng

I have a test case which requires me to log out multiple times. I want log out to be its own test/method. Instead of creating log out method each time, is there another way I can call that method?

```
@Test(priority = 1, groups = {"Regression"})
public void createaccount() throws Exception {}
@Test(priority = 2, groups = {"Regression"})
public void addpayment() throws Exception {}
@Test(priority = 3, groups = {"Regression"})
public void logout() throws Exception {}
@Test(priority = 4, groups = {"Regression"})
public void login() throws Exception {}
@Test(priority = 5, groups = {"Regression"})
public void logout() throws Exception {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the [@AfterMethod](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) annotation. This method will then be called after every test method. If you want to only run it for certain test methods, you can pass in [ITestResult](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/ITestResult.html) to get the test method names. You might also want to include `alwaysRun=true` so that the logout method will be run even if the test fails.

Something like this:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void logout(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("addpayment")) {
            // do logout
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In case you need to make sure it only runs after certain methods, you can use this to check if logout is needed http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

Comment: @Aarjav yes I, need to run it after certain methods. I looked at the doc but I don`t quite get it. Can you lead me to an example? Thanks!

Comment: @HaC thanks but I don`t want to call the log out method after each test method. It has to run after certain methods.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question. Then yes, @Aarjav is right to use ITestResult. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `@AfterMethod` has one problem. You would need to add it to each and every test class. So if all of your test classes have the need to selectively execute some method, you can choose to have this logic included as part of `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener#afterInvocation` by implementing the TestNG listener `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` and wiring it in [ Using the `@Listener` annotation or using the `<listener>` tag or using service loaders. For more details see [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) ]

Inspecting the `ITestResult` object and relying on the method name has a problem that, tomorrow if you refactor your `@Test` method to something else, then you would need to remember to change it in your selective execution place as well. You could instead create a custom annotation say `@Logout`, check for the presence of this annotation in your listener, and if present then have it invoke the method.

Here's a sample implementation of what I am referring to.

Here's how the marker annotation would look like :

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
/**
 * Marker annotation that signifies that a {@link ILogout#signout()} operation has to be performed
 * for the current method.
 */
public @interface Logout {
}
```

Here's how a new interface which defines what should the logout mechanism look like. We will later be leveraging this interface to trigger logouts from the actual test class.

```
/**
 * Defines the logging out capabilities that any test class may possess.
 */
public interface ILogout {
    /**
     * Perform the actual sign out.
     */
    void signout();
}
```

The test class would implement the above interface `ILogout` since it would like to perform selective logout for some `@Test` methods.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTestClass implements ILogout {

    @Test(priority = 1, groups = {"Regression"})
    @Logout //We need a selective logout to be performed for this method.
    public void createaccount() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, groups = {"Regression"})
    public void addpayment() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, groups = {"Regression"})
    public void logout() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test(priority = 4, groups = {"Regression"})
    public void login() throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void signout() {

    }
}
```

Finally, the TestNG listener would look like below :

```
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class MyListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) { }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        Logout logout = method.getTestMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(Logout.class);
        if (logout == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Try and process only if the method that was just now executed by TestNG has the
        //marker annotation.
        Object instance = method.getTestMethod().getInstance();
        //We were asked to logout, but check if the corresponding test class has an implementation
        //for performing the actual logout. If yes, then invoke that directly.
        if (instance instanceof ILogout) {
            ((ILogout) instance).signout();
        }
    }
}
```

This solution would ensure that even though method names undergo refactoring your code is not impacted.